# Dart, adding onClick event to dynamically added elements

Tags: dart, dart-html

A page exists where elements can be dynamically added, currently when an element is added the click event is added as well.

```
//something triggers an element to be added
ButtonElement statusButton = ButtonElement();
statusButton.className = 'status';
statusButton.onClick.listen(doSomething);
div.children.add(statusButton);
```

This works fine but I would prefer to add a single click event for all future elements.

I tried the following without success.

```
ElementList<ButtonElement> statusButtons;
statusButtons = div.querySelectorAll('.status');
statusButtons.onClick.listen(doSomething);
```

How can you use querySelectorAll to add listeners to dynamically added elements?

I am approaching this from a jquery background so perhaps the same issues of adding lots of events to individual elements isn't such an issue in Dart, if so is there a recommended way to write the above code? I would prefer to keep listeners separate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
void addClickEvents() {
  ElementList<ButtonElement> statusButtons = querySelectorAll('.status');

  for (ButtonElement button in statusButtons) {
    String dataListener = button.getAttribute('data-listener');

    if (dataListener != 'true') {
      button.setAttribute('data-listener', 'true');
      button.onClick.listen(printBtnName);
    }
  }
}
```

Try it on DartPad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9221358f0ca1e73acc9d5dfc770ba443

Comment: what's the 2021 way to use the querySelector?